# Wifi disconnecting and reconnecting over and over (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, internet

I'm a super noob when it comes to Linux of any kind, very little experience in a few different distros, trying out Ubuntu. Everything seems to generally work fine except the wifi. It'll stay constant, working perfectly fine for awhile, 10-20 minutes, maybe a half hour, and then for a period of like 5 minutes or so, it'll just constantly disconnect and then reconnect (Giving the prompt to put in the wifi password, though it's saved so I just have to constantly press Enter).

I've been looking through settings and explanations online, and I just don't understand any of what I'm looking at. Not to mention, my Windows boot (It's a dualbooted laptop), as well as my other windows laptop, as well as my friend's computer, has 0 issues with the Wifi, which leads me to believe that it's an issue specific to Ubuntu, and I have no idea how to fix it.

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)

I assume that this is the wireless card the forum needs for me to post the question, but if it's not then I have no idea how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling power management for your wifi controller. Type that into Google or DuckDuckGo and it should bring up several articles. Look for one that explains how to make your changes permanent. You'll need to know the root password. It is not difficult.

Comment: Okay so I've tried to do this, but no matter how many google searches I do, I can't figure out how to edit the file I need to edit in order to make this work. It seems like every page I look at has different solutions, I have no idea which one to use. IDK how you can say this isn't difficult, this is immensely difficult, can't even figure it out with a friend helping.